# Add namespace reference to VS project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, namespaces

I created a "Core" class project library that has several extension methods that I would like to use in other projects that reference this library.

I can make use of these extension methods if I include the extension methods with the `using` keyword. However, these extension methods are used extensively throughout this project, so I would like to avoid adding the `using` statement in practically every file.

Is there a way to include this reference so that I do not need to always include `using` and instead have this namespace available to each class in the project?

Something similar to how in asp.net's web.config I can add:

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
```

and not have to include `using System.Web.Helpers` on each view?

I tried updating my .csproj with the following:

```
<Reference Include="MyClassLibrary.Core" />
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: if you are willing to use it in the class file, you must have that namespace in your class file.

Comment: Extension methods are brought into scope at the namespace level. For example, if you have multiple static classes that contain extension methods in a single namespace named Extensions, they will all be brought into scope by the using Extensions; directive.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: @T.S. but this is not what the OP wants! is it ?

Comment: @T.S. I was hoping there was a way to "globally" include the namespace similar to how we do it in asp.net's web.config

Comment: I understand. But docs say, `Extension methods are brought into scope at the namespace level`. Can you declare globally for all file/classes `system.data`? why extensions should be different?. Think about. Your class is in some namespace. And your namespace must know about other namespace. I tell you more. If your namespace doesn't have any public members, you will not even see it.

Comment: @T.S. this makes sense. If I have my extension methods in namespace that is "above" the library that would use it, does that help? For instance, extension methods would be in `MyLibrary` and then used in `MyLibrary.Business`, would the classes in `MyLibrary.Business` be able to see the extension methods without having to included them with the `using` keyword?

Comment: No. This is why you have `using System; using System.Data;` In your theory, if I just say `using System;` I could see `text, io, data...`